# Haskell-Stack: Access violation error during build

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I've been trying to build my Haskell project for the last couple days using stack and I'm getting an access violation error. From what I understand I have the latest stack version and GHC.

This was all originally working until I added a library to my cabal file. I've now removed it but the error still occurs. I've also reverted back to when my code was definitely working so I'm sure this is something caused by stack.

I've tried uninstalling stack, deleting .stack-work and reinstalling. Then doing a stack setup. I've tried many variations of commands but no results.

I've now also tried creating a new project with Stack and building it and I get the same issue.

```
stack build

Building all executables for `haskell-project' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
haskell-project-0.1.0.0: configure (exe)
Access violation in generated code when reading 000000000e58391a

--  While building custom Setup.hs for package haskell-project-0.1.0.0 using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\5c8418a7 configure --with-ghc=C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.2.2\bin\ghc.EXE --with-ghc-pkg=C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.2.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=C:\sr\snapshots\13cecb13\pkgdb --package-db=C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\haskell-project\.stack-work\install\ccbce92a\pkgdb --libdir=C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\haskell-project\.stack-work\install\ccbce92a\lib --bindir=C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\haskell-project\.stack-work\install\ccbce92a\bin --datadir=C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\haskell-project\.stack-work\install\ccbce92a\share --libexecdir=C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\haskell-project\.stack-work\install\ccbce92a\libexec --sysconfdir=C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\haskell-project\.stack-work\install\ccbce92a\etc --docdir=C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\haskell-project\.stack-work\install\ccbce92a\doc\haskell-project-0.1.0.0 --htmldir=C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\haskell-project\.stack-work\install\ccbce92a\doc\haskell-project-0.1.0.0 --haddockdir=C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\haskell-project\.stack-work\install\ccbce92a\doc\haskell-project-0.1.0.0 --dependency=base=base-4.10.1.0 --dependency=containers=containers-0.5.10.2 --dependency=mtl=mtl-2.2.1-DscMMmDQUE6GBfOSl4qMUH --dependency=parsec=parsec-3.1.11-3BgBURmbRiVF8fgoxhAiBa --dependency=pretty-simple=pretty-simple-2.0.1.0-J3QTM6x6LHL5fhqavYvVhJ --dependency=text=text-1.2.2.2-9VTsh6V7U7hpagw2HDvpZ --extra-include-dirs=C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\bin --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib --enable-tests --enable-benchmarks
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

What would be the steps to fix this or likely causes?

Comment: Probably related: https://github.com/hedgehogqa/haskell-hedgehog/issues/111 https://github.com/commercialhaskell/intero/issues/436

Comment: Looks like this might be different to the ones you mentioned. I've created an issue on GitHub although it would be brilliant if anybody has any ideas. Can't do any coding until I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a temporary solution for anybody who is having the same issue.

I downgraded cabal to version 1.24.0.2 and changed the resolver to using GHC version 8.0.1 (`resolver: ghc-8.0.1`).

After then running `stack solver` I'm now able to build.

Comment: If anybody is having the same issue please comment here to let the devs know there is still a problem. 
https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3765

Answer (score 2):

The [issue #3765](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3765) on the stack tracker has some workarounds for this, in addition to [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48255949/4129231).

The best solution, it seems, is to unset `__COMPAT_LAYER`, which when set to `INSTALLER` can reproduce the bug.

`C:\>set __COMPAT_LAYER=`

The cause might be a bug in some versions of GHC, which is catching exceptions it ought to propagate to the user. If this is the case, there is an underlying problem, and this bug is hiding it.

Do please add a comment on the aforementioned issue, as it will help the maintainers track the prevalence of this problem.